# Visual Studio Code Python Linter is highlighting "problems". How do I disable This?

Tags: visual-studio-code, linter

[image]
This is a Python project I have been working on a few months on for college. After a few weeks of not working on the project I load it up and to my horror the screen is full of error messages. I uninstalled `pylint` and installed `flake8` which fixed some the import errors I was getting with `pylint` but it is still full of error messages.

[image]
Upon unistalling `flake8` and installing `pylint` I am met with this screen.

`pylint` was doing something similar but was also unable to access variables from my imported modules, so installed `flake8` as a replacement. The code runs perfectly fine (fine for someone who has my level of expertise at programming). I want to disable the highlighting to make my code syntactically correct according to `flake8` but proper syntax errors do come up.

Comment: What question did you mean to ask?

Comment: Try restarting VS Code. You can also try disabling Pylint inside VS Code extensions.

Comment: If the Python code is valid then this isn't a Python issue *per se*

Comment: 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. 2) Include also version info for all your Python extensions. Also check if the problem reproduces when on the prerelease channels for these extensions. 3) Try to create a [mre].